# Can't login to Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: lubuntu, login, system

After installation of LAMP + MyPhpAdmin accord to this tutorial [Install lamp](http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/), I can't login to my account.

I see my login screen (with prompt enter login + password).

But after entering it shows me strange error prompt, but so fast that I can't read what exactly happen. And return again to login screen.

I used `Cntrl + Alt + 1` - login to shell.

And tried to view `/var/log/` logs.

***Where exactly should I looking for trouble?

Maybe exist other ways to figure out what is wrong?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect your ethernet cable, open a tty, login and run

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

by using tasksel you probably unchecked ubuntu-desktop which was removed

to install LAMPP use this one line solution instead

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

this depends on all the packages you need which will also be installed